# handle click event with capybara

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, capybara

I'm using capybara with poltergeist driver and I've git his HTML. Can't find a reason why I can't click on this img.

When I'm using `puts find(:css,".item-sku-image a img")['title']` I'm getting this element but with `find(:css,".item-sku-image a img").click` I can't get a click effect. It's just for an example. I've tried with :xpath and the story still the same.

```
<li class="item-sku-image">
   <a data-role="sku" data-sku-id="496" id="sku-2-496" title="32G" href="javascript:;" data-spm-anchor-id="2114.12010208.1000016.6">
      <img src="Snapdragon3000.jpg_50x50.jpg" title="Mi5 Gold  32G" bigpic="Snapdragon3000.jpg"></a></li>
```

phantomJS 2.1.1/capybara 2.8.1

Comment: How are you verifying whether a click happened ([edit] your question to show the code)? Are there any errors?

Comment: there 's no errors . but after clicking on img `<li>` class should be changed to `item-sku-image active` and it's not happening. I checked with `find(:css,".item-sku-image a img").find(:path, "..").find(:path, "..")['class']` and it still `item-sku-image`

Comment: Have you waited between clicking and checking?

Comment: no i have not . If i should how it could be ?

Comment: i've added sleep(10) (!)  between clicking and checking and class has not changed .

Comment: What version of Poltergeist are you using and please show your JS click handler code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) including the link "How to ask questions the smart way."